# duplicate content in different url keys in magento

Tags: url

in our magento site we created lot of categories and assigned same products to

different categories.

this is url links generating for products in our site.

"www.sitename.com/category1/product 1 "

"www.sitename.com/category2/product 1 "

"www.sitename.com/category3/product 1 "

how to make this like as follows :

"www.sitename.com/product 1 "

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Set Use Categories Path for Product URLs to NO.

Note - You might need to re-index Catalog URL rewrites after changing this setting.

Comment: i followed your procedure, than if we click on categories and than we will visit product list page 

and than if we click on product than "category url Path" is removed.

but if we type sitename.com/category 1/product 1 and 

sitename.com/category 2/product 1 in "browser's address bar" than same product information will

show in both urls. i want to display only this url in entire site :

"sitename.com/product1" url. if we go for "sitename.com/category 1/product 1", it should give error.

Comment: Have you run the catalog URL rewrite indexing?

Comment: i reindexed all in system > index management, what else i have to do?